# manage comma separated-fields with edit

Tags: awk, sed, regular-expression, csv

I have text such as the following:

```
Milk,10,2018,110
```

I want to edit it to be as the following output:

```
Milk 10/18 110 NONE NONE NONE NONE
```

By transforming it in these ways:

- removing comma
- using delimiter tab
- add `NONE NONE NONE NONE` as stable word for all info.
- edit month and year such as 10,2018 to be 10/18

Comment: what the number of `None` values depends on?

Comment: it's gonna be stable word on all info.

Comment: @αԋɱҽԃαмєяιcαη please also add your efforts to question..

Comment: Reads a lot like you want someone else to do your work. What you are trying to achieve can be implemented in a number of ways and requires both text parsing and operations against each line. Several commands will help you do this like `awk`, `sed`, `date`, `echo`, several builtin shell commands like `read`, for/while loops, etc. I suggest you break down your problem and research your options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**`Awk`** solution:

```
awk -F',' '{ printf "%s\t%s\t%s\tNONE\tNONE\tNONE\tNONE\n", $1, $2"/"substr($3, 3), $4 }' file
```

The output:

```
Milk    10/18   110 NONE    NONE    NONE    NONE
```

---

Or another way:

```
awk -F',' '{ $5=$6=$7=$8="NONE"; print $1,$2"/"substr($3, 3),$4,$5,$6,$7,$8 }' OFS='\t' file
```

Answer (score 0):

`‰ sed -e 's#\([^,]*\),\([^,]*\),..\([^,]*\),\(.*\)#\1 \2/\3 \4 NONE NONE NONE NONE#' <<< 'Milk,10,2018,110' 
Milk 10/18 110 NONE NONE NONE NONE`